# Can't create a getItem in dynamo with two field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm unable to do an getItem in dynamo with two fields, I keep getting an error "The provided key element does not match the schema", but when I try with just one field everything works perfectly
[image: Trying with one field]

````
  const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB()
  const { email, password } = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const id = '1'
  try {

    const params = {
      TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_USER_TABLE,
      Key: {
        primary_key: {
          S: id
        },
        email: {
          S: email
        }
      },
    }
    
    const result = await dynamoDB.getItem(params).promise();
    
    return response(200, { message: 'Item found', Item: result.Item })
  } catch (error) {
    return response(400, { error: error.message })
  }


};```
````

Answer (score 1):

You only need to provide the partition key when doing a GetItem if no sort key is created on your table, which I am assuming is not. If you want to pass both primary-key and email for your GetItem then you need to make the email attribute a sort key on your table.